# Error cuando selecciono algún elemento en la lista de DataGridView

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, datagrid

Lo que busco es poder usar el datetimpiker para agregar o manipular su contenido. mi objetivo en general es hacer un sistema CRUD usando un datagrid view como referencia y un conjunto de objetos particulares para el ingreso de datados hacia una tabla de una base de dato mysql y que no sea en capas.
Tengo el siguiente error:

> System.FormatException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233033
>   Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
>          at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
>          at Proyecto_final1.Worktable.dgvUsuario_CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) in D:\Manejador de items\Proyecto
>   final1\Proyecto final1\Worktable.cs:line 190
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellContentClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCommonCellContentClick(Int32
>   columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean doubleClick)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnMouseUpInternal(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at Proyecto_final1.Program.Main() in D:\Manejador de items\Proyecto final1\Proyecto final1\Program.cs:line 19
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Aquí el código donde ejecuto:

```
private void dgvUsuario_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    btnEliminar1.Enabled = true; btnEditar1.Enabled = true; btnGuardar1.Enabled = false;
    btnNuevo1.Enabled = false; txtNomUsu.Enabled = true;txtDirecUsu.Enabled = true; txtTelUsu.Enabled = true;
    txtUsu.Enabled = true; txtCorreoUsu.Enabled = true; DTPIniUsu.Enabled = true; CbNivelSeguri.Enabled = true;

    txtCont.Text = dgvUsuario[0, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
    txtUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[1, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
    txtNomUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[2, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
    txtDirecUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[3, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
    txtTelUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[4, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
    txtCorreoUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[5, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
    CbNivelSeguri.Text = dgvUsuario[6, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
    DTPIniUsu.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvUsuario[7, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El error dice:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Esto puede deberse a que **el valor "`string`" no es un valor que pueda ser convertido a `DateTime`**.

En esta línea:

```
DTPIniUsu.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvUsuario[7, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());
```

Debes validar qué datos contiene `dgvUsuario[7, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString()`.

Comprueba primero si puedes convertir el valor.

Ejemplo:

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.Today;
string  miValor = dgvUsuario[7, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

// Comprobar si el valor string se puede convertir a DateTime.
if (DateTime.TryParse(miValor, out temp)) {
    temp = Convert.ToDateTime(miValor);
    // Aquí, la variable "temp" es la fecha convertida del string.
} else {
    // El string no es un DateTime válido.
}
```

Comment: Esto me permitira tomar los valores que eliga del datetimepicker? o lo generara automaticamente?

Comment: @CarlosAlvarez, en tu pregunta no mencionas nada de un `DateTimePicker`. **edita tu pregunta** agregando la descripción completa de lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: gracias y disculpa, no sabia en realidad como leer el problema asi que pregunte a ciegas (no tengo mucha en C#).